# Do minor children require a visa if their parents enter Costa Rica on student visas?

Tags: visas, children, us-citizens, costa-rica, family

I am planning a semester stay in **Costa Rica** with my family for language school and volunteer work.  I think I'm fairly informed about the residency statuses and the mechanics of the 90-day tourist visa (extended by the 72-hour shuffle to Nicaragua or Panama), and I was hoping to get **student visas** for my wife and myself so that we could avoid the logistic hassle of that shuffle.

However, what I haven't yet been able to find a clear answer about is whether all my children *also* need student visas, or if a **parent's visa** is good enough for them to enter.  What will be required for my children aside from valid passports, if anything?

My family and I are US citizens.

Comment: What is your country of citizenship?

Comment: Haha. So you work at SE. Your profile suggests that you are a US citizen. I'll just add that in.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose I could have done this before posting, but maybe the answer here will be helpful to someone else.  I called the consulate of Costa Rica in Houston, Tx and asked this question.  Their answer was that "yes, they have to all have visas or else they would be illegal."

I got a little chuckle out of the phrase, "they would be illegal", but there it is:  **children also have to have visas for entry.**

Comment: I have been researching this all this afternoon, all other kinds of temporary residence visas automatically include all dependents. I think this is the only residence visa excepted from this...

Comment: I accept as a distinct possibility that the lady who I was speaking with at the consulate and I weren't communicating very well.  I plan to go, and if reality turns out differently than what I've presented here, I'll update.